# confused over the jQuery .remove() method

Tags: jquery

I am a bit confused over the remove method.

```
var articleItems;

articleItems = $('.article-item');
var firstArticleItem = articleItems.first();
firstArticleItem.find('ul').remove();
```

This code above is working while this one is not

```
var articleItems;

articleItems = $('.article-item');
var firstArticleItem = articleItems.first();
firstArticleItem.remove('ul');
```

I thought if you add a selector then it will be removed from the DOM.
Could you explain why the second solution is a non working one?

Thank you

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You can pass a param to `remove()`, it's a selector that filters the elements you want to remove. Please see https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: @sorayadragon ahh I see - did not know that :) will remove my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$elems.remove()` removes all elements in the set `$elems`. You can filter the `$elems` set by adding a selector so that only some of them are removed, like so: `$elems.remove('.class')`. This will remove all elements in the set that also have the class "class".

Presumably, what you are trying to do is remove a **child** of the set `$elems`, which is not how it works. It would work however, if `firstArticleItem` was in fact a `<ul>` element, as shown below.

```js
var articleItems;

articleItems = $('.article-item');
var firstArticleItem = articleItems.first();
firstArticleItem.remove('ul');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="article-item">
<li>first item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="article-item">
<li>second item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Yoa are right. I wanted to remove a child of the set firstArticleItem. Now I understand why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The second one **filters** the set of matched elements. In this case, none of the elements in `firstArticleItem` match the `ul` selector so nothing happens.

```
// Remove 'ul' child elements of firstArticleItem
firstArticleItem.find('ul').remove();

// Remove elements from firstArticleItem that also match 'ul'
firstArticleItem.remove('ul');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$el.remove(selector)` is equivalent to `$el.filter(selector).remove()`, not to `$el.find(selector).remove()`. In other words, selector passed as an argument allows you to selectively remove elements from the original collection - not among their descendants. Quoting the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> `.remove([selector])`
>
> **selector**
>
> A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> A selector expression that filters the set of matched elements to be removed.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

The parameter passed to remove is simply a filter.  It will check to see if the jQuery object that called the method matches the selector before removing it.  To remove all descendants that match that selector, use `.find('ul').remove()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The remove method doesn't filter ul items from the current object wrapper.

You need a filter() or find() to do that.